# how to keep music running when app is brought to front after being minimized?

Tags: coronasdk

I am using media.playSound method. the music is working fine but when I minimize the app to lets say open something else, the music stops when I reopen the app. I tried the same thing on android, it's all right there. The music pauses when the app is minimized and then it is resumed when the app is brought to front.

Is there something that needs to be done for it to work on ios devices ??

Comment: How you tried looking at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)?

Comment: mmm... well this would be perfect if I was developing using xcode. I need to know how to do similar things in corona :/

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/36566-run-process-in-background/) is from 25 June 2013 from a SDK staff member in response to a similar question.

> Apple supports a limited number of background modes including playing background music, some GPS features, Newsstand downloads, etc.  Some people have gotten this to work.  But the official answer from the Engineers is "This is unsupported in Corona SDK.  It may not work in future releases. And it doesn't work on Android with Corona SDK at all".  That said, you can take your chances, but no complaining when you update to a later release and your app breaks.
>
> This is unsupported.

The topic takes a turn to talk about the zero support in Andriod so it's safe to say it's unsupported for ios. It's been over a year so I'd suggest finding the page on their site where they talk about added features or ask this question there to find your answer.

Comment: Many people use this on iOS to allow background music to play (iTunes) while the game is playing.  This was something that's best describe as experimental but people found out about it.  It's not something that Corona Labs plans to officially support at this time.